# libgdx - how to change the color of a pixel in a TiledMapTile?

Tags: colors, textures, libgdx

I succeeded in retrieving the exact tile my player is on, at runtime when walking around the tiledmap. I'd like now to add some alpha marks on the terrain when passing over, and to do that I need to modify the color of some pixels of the tile.

I really don't know how to do it right now.. any hints?

thanks.

Comment: Sharing your code will increase the odds of someone being able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to draw decorations on top of the tiles, rather than modifying the tiles themselves. The tile images are shared across all cells using a tile, so if you modify the tile itself you would see the change everywhere it was used. Further, modifying the texture is a relatively expensive operation that you probably should try to avoid.

To draw on top the tiles, you might draw additional sprites, or use a custom shader.

Comment: Yes, decorations is the closest definition. sort of footsteps.

Comment: I tried to do with multiple arraylist<footsteps>, one for each game entity, of fixed size and fixed lifespan (each footstep lasts a fixed amount of ms than fades away), but performance drops unless the footsteps queue is maintained short. I used shaperender for footsteps on terrain.